# Ошибка при запуске стандартного сервера на Flask: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, flask

[Решено]

При попытке запустить сервер через `flask run`  выводит слeдующее:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\games\python\Lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "d:\games\python\Lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "d:\games\python\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 774, in inner fd=fd)
File "d:\games\python\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 666, in make_server
passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
File "d:\games\python\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 577, in __init__
self.address_family), handler)
File "d:\games\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "d:\games\python\Lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
File "d:\games\python\Lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Используется `venv` . Flask установлен. `$env:FLASK_APP="1.py"` введено.

При попытке активации того-же кода без `venv` через set `FLASK_APP=1.py` выдает:
    Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

```
Error: Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP 
environment variable.

For more information see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/
```

Собственно сам код `1.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: У вас имя компьютера кириллицей написано?

Comment: Проблема оказалась в русском названии компьютера. Спасибо всем помогавшим